# How do I add 11 to %%i?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I tried

```
set /p input2=
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%input2%) do ren text_%%i.txt worked_%%i+11.txt
```

and it just tries to rename text_1.txt to worked_1+11.txt
How do I do it properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question you want a mathematical addition.So you'll need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and `set /a` :

```
@echo off

set /p input2=provide a number
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (1;1;%input2%) do (
 set num=%%i
 set /a nump11=num+11
 ren text_%%i.txt worked_!nump11!.txt
)
```

Comment: You don't need the num variable. You can define nump11 directly as `%%i+11`

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks, I decided to write a solution that does not use delayed expansion and does not require CALL. But normally I would just use delayed expansion as npocmaka has done.

```
@echo off
set /p input2=
set /a end=input2+11
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%A in (
  '(for /l %%N in (12 1 %end%^) do @echo %%N^)^|findstr /n "^"'
) do echo ren text%%A.txt worked_%%B.txt
```